# Who stole my file descriptors?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I'm learning a `socketpair()` function. File descriptors returned by that function are 5 and 6. How can I check what files/sockets descriptors 3 and 4 were assigned to?

Comment: Why do you care? Why are you checking what file descriptor values are?

Comment: strace will tell you something.

Comment: @iharob: because, I'm learning, man

Comment: Perhaps you called `socketpair()` once before and missed to close the socket descriptors returned?

Comment: @alk: I tested behavior of such a program before, it closes a file descriptor on exit, no close() required really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve on [Frederik Deweerdt' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451641/frederik-deweerdt) (and assuming a Linux system), for debugging purposes you might add the following (for Linux systems) after a *successful* call to [socketpair(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) (so after the check that it did not fail):

```
 char cmdbuf[64];
 snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), 
           "/bin/ls -l /proc/%d/fd/", (int) getpid());
 system(cmdbuf);
```

but this is only a disgusting debugging hack. You might perhaps [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) then [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) the `/proc/self/fd/` directory (and don't forget to `closedir` it), if you really want such an information from your running program (of course `opendir` will consume a file descriptor to read the directory...). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details.

Alternatively, if your program is running in a process of pid 1234, just type `ls -l /proc/1234/fd/` in some other terminal.

You might also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) your entire program.

BTW, why do you care about which file descriptors are used?

Of course, you could [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) `/proc/self/fd/4` if you want, from inside your program, to understand how is the file descriptor 4 used in it. Notice that `readlink` takes a file path, not an opened file descriptor.

Comment: This lib/tools http://procps.sourceforge.net/ used to help me setup up some debug code for pulling `/proc` related info.

Comment: @el.pescado: Sure, but there are enough, "*normally*" at least ;-)

Comment: But still, you have to remember that *those are not the file descriptors you're looking for* ;)

Answer (score 3):

Linux specific answer follows:

A possible way would be to add a `pause(3)` call right after the `sockerpair()` call. This will pause the program and give you the opportunity to take a look at '/proc/[pid of the program]/fd'. That should give you some information on what those other open file descriptors are.

Comment: No /proc/fd on my Linux distribution (kali), lots of /proc/some_number/fd, but I don't have an idea what directory I'm looking for exactly

Comment: @oleg.s: `some_number` would be the process-id of the program in question.

Comment: @oleg.s, as @alk said, it's `/proc/<pid of your program>/fd`, rather than `/proc/fd`. That directory is made of symlinks that link the fd numbers to the actual files that were open. For example: `lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 17 08:34 0 -> /dev/pts/0`. That means fd `0` is opened on file `/dev/pts/0`